# Using the Runge-Kutta integration method in a system

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

```
h=0.005;                                            
x = 0:h:40;                                         
y = zeros(1,length(x)); 
y(1) = 0;                                         
F_xy = ;                    

for i=1:(length(x)-1)                              
    k_1 = F_xy(x(i),y(i));
    k_2 = F_xy(x(i)+0.5*h,y(i)+0.5*h*k_1);
    k_3 = F_xy((x(i)+0.5*h),(y(i)+0.5*h*k_2));
    k_4 = F_xy((x(i)+h),(y(i)+k_3*h));

    y(i+1) = y(i) + (1/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)*h;  
end
```

I have the following code, I think it's right. I know there's parts missing on the F_xy because this is my follow up question.

I have dx/dt = = −x(2 − y) with t_0 = 0, x(t_0) = 1

and dy/dt = y(1 − 2x) with t_0 = 0, y(t_0) = 2.

My question is that I don't know how to get these equations in to the code. All help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are using both `t` and `x` as independent variable in an inconsistent manner. Going from the actual differential equations, the independent variable is `t`, while the dependent variables of the 2-dimensional system are `x` and `y`. They can be combined into a state vector `u=[x,y]` Then one way to encode the system close to what you wrote is

```
h=0.005;                                            
t = 0:h:40;   
u0 = [1, 2]                                       
u = [ u0 ]                                         
function udot = F(t,u)
     x = u(1); y = u(2);
     udot = [ -x*(2 - y),  y*(1 - 2*x) ]
end                 

for i=1:(length(t)-1)                              
    k_1 = F(t(i)      , u(i,:)        );
    k_2 = F(t(i)+0.5*h, u(i,:)+0.5*h*k_1);
    k_3 = F(t(i)+0.5*h, u(i,:)+0.5*h*k_2);
    k_4 = F(t(i)+    h, u(i,:)+    h*k_3);

    u(i+1,:) = u(i,:) + (h/6)*(k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4);  
end
```

with a solution output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is `F_xy` your derivative function?

If so, simply write it as a helper function or function handle. For example,

```
F_xy=@(x,y)[-x*(2-y);y*(1-2*x)];
```

Also note that your `k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4, y(i)` are all two-dimensional. You need to re-size your `y` and rewrite the indices in your iterating steps accordingly.

Comment: Then the second stage of RK4 has to be `k2 = F_xy(x(i)+0.5*h*k1(1), y(i)+0.5*h*k1(2))`. The update for the next point has also to be made with care, `dxy = (h/6)*k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4); x(i+1)=x(i)+dxy(1); y(i+1)=y(i)+dxy(2);`.

Comment: I am only answering matlab questions. OP asked how to code a 2-dimensional function. I would rather OP clarify his question himself instead of us inferring what he needs.

Comment: I should write more to the motivation of my comment. I found it inconsistent from an abstract/mathematical POV to mix two scalar variables on one side with a vector on the other. The rest of the comment shows that it is well possible to go on with that, but that from the POV of code complexity it is probably a better idea to resolve this mix-up to one or the other side. My preferred variant towards full vectorization is in my answer.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't review RK4 nor did I dig my own code up and answer based on how i would implement it. I feel the OP can clarify his question more. Also, I think he needs help with the math -- not matlab.